# Solving Method Not Allowed Http Exception in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I want some values in my table editable, so I created this simple custom form. But this will throw error of method not allowed http exception.Any help?

```
 <form action="{{ url('/idx-test/update-this-student/'. $student->id)}}" class="" method="POST">//changing this to put, patch does not solve the error
```

Route

```
Route::post('/idx-test/update-this-student/{id}', 'StudentController@updateThisStudent'); //again changing this to patch,or put does not help
```

Controller

```
public function updateThisStudent(StudentRequest $request, $id)
{
    $student = Student::findOrFail($id);

    $student->update($request->all());

   // return redirect('city');
   echo "updated";
}
```

StudentRequest

```
   public function rules()
{

    return [
        'firstname'    => 'required|alpha|min:2|max:10',
        'lastname'     => 'required|alpha|min:2|max:10',
        'bday'         => 'required|date',
        'address'      => 'required|min:10',
        'zip'          => 'required|min:4|max:10',
        'phone'        => 'required|digits:7',
        'mobile'       => 'required|digits:11',
        'email'        => 'required|email',
        'city_id'      => 'required',
        'yearlevel_id' => 'required',
        'section_id'   => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Comment: What does the StudentRequest class look like?

Comment: @henrik just some sort of validation.It works well when adding new Student. I don't think that's the cause of error.Anyway, I updated the question

Comment: what does StudentRequest class?

Answer (score 0):

By adding this small piece of code

```
 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
```

My problem solve